# Record remains in SQLite Android device even after rebuild and new deploy Xamarin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xamarin.forms, rebuild

I have noticed very strange behavior. I am developing Xamarin.Forms app for Android and until now, when rebuilding solution and deploying app to the remote device all data in sqlite was being flushed like in fresh install.

Now, when I rebuild and deploy, in SQLite DB data is being flushed, erased all apart from one record.

Anyone can help me figure out what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43712610/10133988).

I disabled android backup option and uninstalled the app. after new build data was not being present anymore.